# android - best way to load multiple images locally

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

what is the best approach to load multiple images from local android device? do i still need to cache the bitmap or should i just load the bitmap directly to imageview? is there a library that you can recommend? i have read about other libraries such as glide, picasso, etc. but i think they are intended for downloading images from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most image loading libraries support multiple sources, not just http. Both [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) allow you to load images from file paths, content Uris, resources, assets, and more.

See Glide's [RequestManager](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestListener.html) class for all of the available types Glide currently supports.

Don't re-invent the wheel, use a library.